# Finding design flaws in [] operator of a matrix implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

In a C++ program, here are two operator headings used as setters and getters for a matrix implementation that is not shown.

```
double* Matrix::operator[](unsigned int row) const throw (MatrixException);
double* Matrix::operator[](unsigned int row) throw (MatrixException);
```

Without knowing any further about the implementation of the aforementioned operators, just by looking at how the above operators are defined what would be the design flaw in the matrix program if both these methods are implemented.

Clarification about how [] operator works:
The matrix is set as follows:

```
Matrix *a = new Matrix(1,2); //matrix with one row and two columns
a[0][0] = 3.0; 
a[0][1] = 2.3;

//to access a matrix value
double* b = a[0][1];
delete a;
```

Edit: what would you change in the operator definition to fix the design flaws?

Comment: For starters, they should return references, not pointers. Also, exception specifications (the 'throw' next to the function) are deprecated.

Comment: throw specification like this is confusing, misleading and removed(deprecated) from c++11. good riddance

Answer (score 0):

First design flaw is the use of *exception specifications*, deprecated in **C++11**.

Second design flaw is the fact that you can index out of row columns and there is no way for the class to check it. I.e.,

```
Matrix a( 1, 2 );
double b = a[0][4];
```

Bounds checking would be possible by the use of a *proxy*.

```
struct Matrix {
    struct Column {
        double operator[](unsigned int column);
    };

    Column operator[](unsigned int row);
};
```

Finally, your example is totally bogus. You declare `a` as a *pointer*, so when you subscript `a[0][0]` you are actually subscripting the pointer first, then the row.

Comment: how would you modify the operator definition to check for bounds?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few flaws.

The most obvious one is the unnecessary use of dynamic memory with manual memory management. Any time you see `delete` you pretty much know something is wrong, and any time you see `new` you should be suspicious.

```
Matrix a(1, 2); // no new needed
a[0][0] = 3.0;
a[0][1] = 2.3;
double * b = a[0][1];
// no delete needed
```

This prevents memory leaks entirely. It also avoids the bug you included of not actually indexing the array (you needed to use `(*a)[0][0]` to get the first element).

Second, you should return a reference to the value, not a pointer.

Third, you should a function that returns the value and takes two indexes as the parameters, rather than overloading an `operator[]` to return an array that you then have to dereference again. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html

This allows you to check the bounds, assuming that the `Matrix` knows what its own size is (it would have to store two integer data members).

```
double const & Matrix::at(size_t const row, size_t const column) const {
    check_bounds(row, column);
    return implementation_detail();
}
```

With an obvious implementation for the `double &` version. As it stands, your `const` member function version returns a `double *` instead of making the `const` transitive by returning a `double const *` (although a reference is still preferred).

Another potential flaw is that a generic class like a `Matrix` should probably be parameterized on the type:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    ...
};
```

Your example, therefore, would actually be using a `Matrix<double>` as the type.

Finally, I would say no to exception specifications. They tend to cause more bugs than they fix, which is why they were deprecated in C++11.